# Can't instantiate FloatingActionButton class

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I'm following Udacity Google's android basic course data storage. I am not able to instantiate FloatingActionButton class.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.myfab)
```

It says can't resolve symbol 'FloatingActionButton.'
If someone could help me to create FloatingActionButton, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add the support:design in build.gradle: module app to dependencies.

`compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

if using gradle plugin 3.0+

`api 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It worked! But I have a question though. Even though it worked, it still shows red swiggly line underneath the line "compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'". It says 'This support library should not use a different version (27) than the compileSdkVersion (28).

Comment: means you have to update your support library from version 27 to 28 and problem will get resolve. If the answer was useful up mark the answer.